# How to convert UTF8 to string using string functions in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

I have a source table where free form text entered via an front end application gets stored as VARBINARY (SQL Server). While loading Greenplum the field was cast into VARCHAR field. Loaded as a UTF8 value, I am facing issues in encode/decode this field into a meaningful text.

Couple of things I have tried till now, used PSQL 8.2 String functions and the UTF-8 decodes online tools to understand the expected result.

Encoded to base64 but that still produces the utf-8 value only

```
SELECT encode('0x205361742046656220312031363A32313A303320 utf-8','base64');
--Output
--MHgyMDUzNjE3NDIwNDY2NTYyMjAzMTIwMzEzNjNBMzIzMTNBMzAzMzIwIHV0Zi04
```

Using an UTF8 decode online tools, if run this '0x205361742046656220312031363A32313A303320' through the decoder - it produces ' Sat Feb 1 16:21:03 ' and that is my expected result.

Any advice/help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The equivalent of `varbinary` would be `bytea`, not `varchar`

Comment: You should cast the varbinary to text in SQL Server and then load the meaningful text data into Greenplum.